# Slow join on geometry fields

Tags: postgresql, join, geometry

My situation is somewhat similar to [this earlier question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/281629/geospatial-join-using-st-contains-or-st-within-seems-slow-with-costly-query-and): In PostgreSQL I have one table containing point geometries (P), and another containing polygons (G). I would like to join on the geometry field, e.g.

```
SELECT P.ID, G.SHAPE
FROM POINTS P
JOIN NL_1KM G ON ST_CONTAINS(G.SHAPE, P.SHAPE)
```

The difference is that my polygons are a rectangular 1×1 km grid, so I don't think ST_Subdivide will help.

The grid table has ~126,000 records, and there are currently ~280 points. Both tables have a spatial index, all geometries are WGS84.

I would think that only 280 lookups on the grid would be required, but this takes roughly one minute. The same query with a 10km grid (1350 records) takes only 0.6 seconds

This is the query plan for the 1km grid:

```
QUERY PLAN
Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..9816799.62 rows=12459941 width=600) (actual time=2964.853..66014.294 rows=284 loops=1)
  Output: w.id, g.shape
  Join Filter: st_contains(g.shape, (w.shape)::st_geometry)
  Rows Removed by Join Filter: 37505400
  ->  Seq Scan on myschema.nl_1km g  (cost=0.00..4571.58 rows=125858 width=596) (actual time=0.025..41.477 rows=125858 loops=1)
        Output: g.objectid, g.cellcode, g.eoforigin, g.noforigin, g.shape
  ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..24.45 rows=297 width=484) (actual time=0.000..0.012 rows=298 loops=125858)
        Output: w.id, w.shape
        ->  Seq Scan on myschema.points w  (cost=0.00..22.97 rows=297 width=484) (actual time=0.007..0.106 rows=298 loops=1)
              Output: w.id, w.shape
Planning Time: 0.293 ms
Execution Time: 66014.393 ms
```

Note that the `st_geometry` data type in the execution plan is an ArcGIS data type.

What am I missing?

#### Update, a few minutes after I posted...

One thing I was missing is that using ST_Intersects instead of ST_Contains makes things so fast, it almost scares me (0.06 sec). The new query plan shows that the spatial index on the grid is now used. So, my question should have been, why does ST_Contains not use the spatial index? If anyone has an answer to that?

Answer (score 0):

I can only answer from the PostgreSQL/PostGIS point of view, as I know nothing about ArcGIS.

The clue is the line `st_contains(g.shape, (w.shape)::st_geometry)` from the plan.

`st_geometry` is an ArcGIS data type, so it looks like

1. `points.shape` is of type `st_geometry`, but `nl_1km.shape` is of a different data type (let's assume it is a PostGIS `geometry`)
2. the function `st_contains` is not a PostGIS function, but an ArcGIS function.

I don't know how well ArcGIS supports GiST indexes, but if there is a type cast from `st_geometry` to `geometry`, you could make use of PostGIS:

```
SELECT p.id, g.shape
FROM points AS p
   JOIN nl_1km AS g ON st_contains(g.shape::geometry, p.shape);
```

That requires an index on the PostGIS geometry:

```
CREATE INDEX ON nl_1km USING gist ((g.shape::geometry));
```

Comment: Thanks, but as I mentioned, both tables involved already have a spatial index, the one on the grid is literally the same as your suggestion :-) I believe st_geometry might a function installed by ArcGIS.

Comment: `st_geometry` is a data type, not a function. That type cast prevents you from using the index. Without knowing the column definition and what that `st_geometry` is, I cannot say more.

Comment: My bad, because of the *st_* prefix, I mistakenly thought st_geometry was the geometry type used by postgis. It is however a custom type provided by ArcGIS, including many functions with the same name, eg st_contains, st_intersects, etc. I should probably move this to https://gis.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Aha. That would mean that the `st_contains` function in the execution plan operates on that ArcGIS data type. Then it cannot be the PostGIS function `st_contains`. If it is an ArcGIS function, that would explain why it cannot make use of a GiST index. Pray tell: what is the data type of `points.shape`?

Comment: Points are the same datatype, ie st_geometry. The index is created by ArcGIS as well, and is defined as `CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS a134_ix1 ON myschema.points USING gist(shape)`.

Comment: So you are saying that the question is not about PostGIS at all, right?

Comment: Probably. It may be a PostgreSQL question, after all it's still PostgreSQL that decides whether or not to use an index. For `st_contains` it doesn't, for `st_intersects` it does. It may also be an ArcGIS issue

Comment: I agree. I will adapt my answer.